# Touching fields causes react-hook-form to become dirty

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form

I have a problem with react-hook-form whereby simply "touching" a field (clicking into it then clicking elsewhere) is causing the formState.isDirty to be true. I've reproduced the problem in this codesandbox:

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-dirty-by-touch-p8x6j

I'm loading a record from the server and calling reset() so that it's regarded as the new baseline, and this is probably the cause of the problem. But, being a dynamic form, I need to retrieve the object form the server to load into the form, so I see no way around this. All I want is for the formState.isDirty to remain false as long as the values don't actually change.

I don't have this problem with more complex components (such as react-select) for which I'm just calling register('whatever') myself, and it's only the native HTML inputs where I'm using ref={register} that are having this problem.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import { yupResolver } from "@hookform/resolvers/yup";
import * as yup from "yup";

export default function App() {
  interface MyObject {
    testing: string;
    id: number;
  }

  const blankObject: MyObject = {
    testing: "Default value",
    id: 0
  };

  const [obj, setObj] = useState(blankObject);

  const schema = yup.object().shape({
    testing: yup.string().max(40)
  });

  const { register, handleSubmit, formState, reset, errors } = useForm<
    MyObject
  >({
    resolver: yupResolver(schema),
    defaultValues: blankObject
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      const newObj = {
        testing: "Pretend this came from the server",
        id: 123
      };
      setObj(newObj);
      reset(newObj);
    }, 2000);
  }, [reset]);

  const onSubmit = (data: MyObject) => {
    alert(JSON.stringify(data));
  };

  const onReset = () => {
    reset();
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
      {obj.id === 0 ? (
        <p>Please wait...</p>
      ) : (
        <div>
          <p>ID: {obj.id}</p>
          <label>Enter text: </label>
          <input
            type="text"
            name="testing"
            ref={register}
            autoComplete="off"
            style={{ width: "50%" }}
            defaultValue={obj.testing}
          />
          {errors.testing && (
            <div style={{ color: "#ff0000" }}>{errors.testing?.message}</div>
          )}

          <pre>{JSON.stringify(formState, null, 2)}</pre>

          <input type="submit" />
          <input type="button" value="reset" onClick={onReset} />
        </div>
      )}
    </form>
  );
}
```

I could probably get rid of the ref={register} and handle the registration manually, but it seems a bit beside the point of react-hook-form to do so.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How React hook form verifies a form is dirty or not is based on deep compare `defaultValues`.

here are your example's `defaultValues`: (after the reset)

```
const newObj = {
  testing: "Pretend this came from the server",
  id: 123
};
```

however, there is no such field as `id` got registered at hook form. so the comparison will also be a mismatch because `id` is missing.

The following example may give you a better context.

https://codesandbox.io/s/snowy-bush-jjcqk?file=/src/App.tsx

Comment: If I amend my example to add "defaultValues: blankObject" to the useForm constructor, it still causes the form to become dirty just by focusing and unfocusing the field.

Comment: @MarcFearby the problem is where is the `id` input?

Comment: I see what you mean. Drats. I was hoping to use an existing object interface (which has other fields that I want to ignore for this particular form). So I'm going to have to specifically set only those properties I'm interested in validating as my defaultValues and also whenever I call reset? :-(

Comment: i think you can try to set shouldUnregister: false at useForm, it may work out for you, then id will be a virtual input.

Comment: I didn't do that but I am only referring to the testing property in my blankObject and when calling reset() and it's fine. I was just trying to be lazy, I guess :-)

Comment: Incidentally, the 'data' argument passed to onSubmit only ever had a 'testing' property before, even when I was passing an object to reset() which had superfluous properties, so that part knew that I was only interested in that field and not 'id'.

Comment: Yes. Thanks for your assistance.